# When using object type stores an int value, why the object.GetType() returns system.Int32?

Tags: c#

The code like below:

```
object i = 11;

Console.WriteLine(i.GetType());
```

It prints out "System.Int32", why? I thought it should be "system.object".

Comment: The type is The exact runtime type of the current instance

Comment: The title confuses me at first.. Not sure if repharsing is good: "why object.GetType() doesn't return System.Object". By googling that found [that article](http://tooslowexception.com/how-does-gettype-work/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`GetType()` returns the *actual type* of the object that the value refers to. It doesn't return the type of the *variable* used to access the object. So as a simpler example:

```cs
object x = "this is a string";
Console.WriteLine(x.GetType()); // Prints System.String
```

In this case, the type is "boxed `System.Int32`" - but most of .NET doesn't differentiate between "a regular value type" and "the boxed type equivalent to the value type", including `GetType()`.

Comment: To add, just calling `GetType()` on a value type will box it (since `GetType()` is defined in `object`), so you'll get the same result from e.g. `5.GetType()`.